# How to make g++ do NOT distinguish <string> and <string.h>

Tags: c++, gcc, compatibility

Recently, I met a very annoying problem. I need to compile some old C++ codes which was compiled with a very old g++ version 4.1.2.

I couldn't find g++ version that old now, so I used g++ 4.4.7 to compile it, but there were many errors like `error: ‘snprintf’ was not declared in this scope`.

After some work, I found g++ 4.1.2 do NOT distinguish `<string>` from `<string.h>`, also `<stdio>` from `<stdio.h>`, etc.. But g++ 4.4.7 DOES. So these errors happened.

For some reasons, I couldn't modify the old source code. Is there a way that can make the newer g++ ignore the difference between `<string>` and `<string.h>`?

Comment: `srting` and `string.h` are different headers. If older version doesn't differentiate then that probably can be considered as bug. I can't see you can tell `g++` not to differentiate between them.

Comment: As workaround, you may force gcc to always include `<string.h>` with `-include`

Comment: I'm pretty sure gcc 2.95.3 got this right, so I don't think there was a regression around 4.1.2. Instead, I think you're mixing C and C++ rules. C++ headers _may_ include other headers. In particular, `<string>` _may_ include `<string.h>`. You cannot rely on that either way.

Comment: @MSalters you are right, I tried to print the headers by command `g++ tt.cpp -M` on the compiler with g++ 4.1.2, and `string.h` was listed there. So `<string>` include `<string.h>` with g++ 4.1.2. But `<string.h>` was NOT included with g++ 4.4.7.

Comment: That probably makes G++4.4.7 compile just a bit faster, by not dragging in an extra unasked header. But yes, it breaks code which relies on such unfounded assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a directory in your project (let's call it `foo`);
2. Create `foo/string` and `foo/string.h` as symlinks to whichever header works;
3. Add [`-Ifoo`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-I-916) to GCC's compilation flags.

Both symlinks will now be used when you include `<string>` or `<string.h>`, and will redirect to the actual system header.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen `string` and `string.h` usually implemented as just files (the first `string` filename is without an extension).

To not include the standard include paths you need to specify: **-nostdinc**